# PHP DELETE RECORD AFTER 6 HOURS

Tags: php

please i'm trying to delete a record after 6 hours in database but all efforts have failed. below is the function, i'm a newbie please.

```php
function chektime()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM live_message";
    $row = array();
    $sql2 = $this->conn->query($sql);
    if ($sql2->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($res = $sql2->fetch_assoc()) {
            $row[] = $res;
            foreach ($row as $rows) {
                $id = $rows['id_live_message'];
                $timers = $rows['created_at'];
                $newtime = strtotime($timers);
                $t = time();
                $timediff = $newtime - $t;
                $neetousetime = $timediff / 3600 % 7;
            }
            if ($neetousetime >= 4) {
                $timedetect = "DELETE FROM live_message WHERE id_live_message ='$id' ";
                $sql = $this->conn->query($timedetect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh! I'm not going to try and unpick that. Please reformat your question using a code block for the code and indent so that it's readable.

Answer (score 3):

To delete all records older than 6 hours, you can use a single SQL operation - no need to fetch anything to the server. I'm assuming you are using MySQL:

```
$this->conn->query('DELETE FROM live_message WHERE created_at<NOW()- INTERVAL 6 HOUR');
```

Comment: wow thanks buddie, yes MySQL is my database